# How do you randomly zero a bit in an integer?

Tags: c#, .net, vb.net, bit-manipulation

**Updated with newer answer and better test**

Let's say I have the number 382 which is 101111110.

How could I randomly turn a bit which is not 0 to 0?

The why;

Since people ask me why, I simply need to do this, removing a bit from an integer.

based on the answer here is the result(working one)
I ran this

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Collections;
using System.Linq;
using System.Diagnostics;

namespace ConsoleApplication1
{
    class Program
    {
        static Random random;
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            Stopwatch sw;
            int[] test = new int[10] { 382, 256, 1, 257, 999, 555, 412, 341, 682, 951 };

            random = new Random(42);
            for (int j = 0; j < 10; j++)
            {
                sw = Stopwatch.StartNew();
                for (int i = 0; i < 1000000; i++)
                    Perturb(test[j]);
                sw.Stop();
                Console.WriteLine("Perturb " + sw.Elapsed.TotalSeconds.ToString("0.#######") + " seconds for " + test[j].ToString());
                Debug.WriteLine("> Perturb " + sw.Elapsed.TotalSeconds.ToString("0.#######") + " seconds for " + test[j].ToString() + "  ");
            }

            random = new Random(42);
            for (int j = 0; j < 10; j++)
            {
                sw = Stopwatch.StartNew();
                for (int i = 0; i < 1000000; i++)
                    FastPerturb(test[j]);
                sw.Stop();
                Console.WriteLine("FastPerturb " + sw.Elapsed.TotalSeconds.ToString("0.#######") + " seconds for " + test[j].ToString());
                Debug.WriteLine("> FastPerturb " + sw.Elapsed.TotalSeconds.ToString("0.#######") + " seconds for " + test[j].ToString() + "  ");
            }

            random = new Random(42);
            for (int j = 0; j < 10; j++)
            {
                sw = Stopwatch.StartNew();
                for (int i = 0; i < 1000000; i++)
                    SetRandomTrueBitToFalse(test[j]);
                sw.Stop();
                Console.WriteLine("SetRandomTrueBitToFalse " + sw.Elapsed.TotalSeconds.ToString("0.#######") + " seconds for " + test[j].ToString());
                Debug.WriteLine("> SetRandomTrueBitToFalse " + sw.Elapsed.TotalSeconds.ToString("0.#######") + " seconds for " + test[j].ToString() + "  ");
            }

            random = new Random(42);
            for (int j = 0; j < 10; j++)
            {
                sw = Stopwatch.StartNew();
                for (int i = 0; i < 1000000; i++)
                    flipRandomBit(test[j]);
                sw.Stop();
                Console.WriteLine("flipRandomBit " + sw.Elapsed.TotalSeconds.ToString("0.#######") + " seconds for " + test[j].ToString());
                Debug.WriteLine("> flipRandomBit " + sw.Elapsed.TotalSeconds.ToString("0.#######") + " seconds for " + test[j].ToString() + "  ");
            }

            random = new Random(42);
            for (int j = 0; j < 10; j++)
            {
                sw = Stopwatch.StartNew();
                for (int i = 0; i < 1000000; i++)
                    oneBitsIndexes(test[j]);
                sw.Stop();
                Console.WriteLine("oneBitsIndexes " + sw.Elapsed.TotalSeconds.ToString("0.#######") + " seconds for " + test[j].ToString());
                Debug.WriteLine("> oneBitsIndexes " + sw.Elapsed.TotalSeconds.ToString("0.#######") + " seconds for " + test[j].ToString() + "  ");
            }

            random = new Random(42);
            for (int j = 0; j < 10; j++)
            {
                sw = Stopwatch.StartNew();
                for (int i = 0; i < 1000000; i++)
                    ClearOneBit(test[j]);
                sw.Stop();
                Console.WriteLine("ClearOneBit " + sw.Elapsed.TotalSeconds.ToString("0.#######") + " seconds for " + test[j].ToString());
                Debug.WriteLine("> ClearOneBit " + sw.Elapsed.TotalSeconds.ToString("0.#######") + " seconds for " + test[j].ToString() + "  ");
            }

            random = new Random(42);
            for (int j = 0; j < 10; j++)
            {
                sw = Stopwatch.StartNew();
                for (int i = 0; i < 1000000; i++)
                    FlipRandomTrueBit(test[j]);
                sw.Stop();
                Console.WriteLine("FlipRandomTrueBit " + sw.Elapsed.TotalSeconds.ToString("0.#######") + " seconds for " + test[j].ToString());
                Debug.WriteLine("> FlipRandomTrueBit " + sw.Elapsed.TotalSeconds.ToString("0.#######") + " seconds for " + test[j].ToString() + "  ");
            }

            random = new Random(42);
            for (int j = 0; j < 10; j++)
            {
                sw = Stopwatch.StartNew();
                for (int i = 0; i < 1000000; i++)
                    ClearRandomBit(test[j]);
                sw.Stop();
                Console.WriteLine("ClearRandomBit " + sw.Elapsed.TotalSeconds.ToString("0.#######") + " seconds for " + test[j].ToString());
                Debug.WriteLine("> ClearRandomBit " + sw.Elapsed.TotalSeconds.ToString("0.#######") + " seconds for " + test[j].ToString() + "  ");
            }

            Console.Read();
        }
        public static int Perturb(int data)
        {
            if (data == 0) return 0;

            int minBits = (data & 0xFFFF0000) == 0 ? 16 : 32;

            int newData = data;
            do
            {
                newData &= ~(1 << random.Next(minBits));
            } while (newData == data);

            return newData;
        }

        public static int FastPerturb(int data)
        {
            if (data == 0) return 0;

            int bit = 0;
            while (0 == (data & (bit = 1 << random.Next(32)))) ;

            return data & ~bit;
        }

        private static Int32 SetRandomTrueBitToFalse(Int32 p)
        {
            List<int> trueBits = new List<int>();
            for (int i = 0; i < 31; i++)
            {
                if ((p >> i & 1) == 1)
                {
                    trueBits.Add(i);
                }
            }
            if (trueBits.Count > 0)
            {
                int index = random.Next(0, trueBits.Count);
                return p & ~(1 << trueBits[index]);
            }
            return p;
        }

        public static int getBitCount(int bits)
        {
            bits = bits - ((bits >> 1) & 0x55555555);
            bits = (bits & 0x33333333) + ((bits >> 2) & 0x33333333);
            return ((bits + (bits >> 4) & 0xF0F0F0F) * 0x1010101) >> 24;
        }

        public static int flipRandomBit(int data)
        {
            int index = random.Next(getBitCount(data));
            int mask = data;

            for (int i = 0; i < index; i++)
                mask &= mask - 1;
            mask ^= mask & (mask - 1);

            return data ^ mask;
        }

        public static int oneBitsIndexes(int data)
        {
            if (data > 0)
            {
                var oneBitsIndexes = Enumerable.Range(0, 31)
                                               .Where(i => ((data >> i) & 0x1) != 0).ToList();
                // pick a random index and update the source value bit there from 1 to 0
                data &= ~(1 << oneBitsIndexes[random.Next(oneBitsIndexes.Count)]);
            }
            return data;
        }

        static private int ClearOneBit(int originalValue)
        {
            if (originalValue == 0)
                return 0; // All bits are already set to 0, nothing to do

            int mask = 0;
            do
            {
                int n = random.Next(32);
                mask = 1 << n;
            } while ((mask & originalValue) == 0); // check that this bit is not 0

            int newValue = originalValue & ~mask; // clear this bit
            return newValue;
        }

        public static BitArray FlipRandomTrueBit(BitArray bits)
        {
            List<int> trueBits = new List<int>();

            for (int i = 0; i < bits.Count; i++)
                if (bits[i])
                    trueBits.Add(i);

            if (trueBits.Count > 0)
            {
                int index = random.Next(0, trueBits.Count);
                bits[trueBits[index]] = false;
            }

            return bits;
        }

        public static int FlipRandomTrueBit(int input)
        {
            BitArray bits = new BitArray(new int[] { input });
            BitArray flipedBits = FlipRandomTrueBit(bits);

            byte[] bytes = new byte[4];
            flipedBits.CopyTo(bytes, 0);

            int result = BitConverter.ToInt32(bytes, 0);
            return result;
        }

        static int ClearRandomBit(int value)
        {
            return unchecked((int)ClearRandomBit((ulong)(uint)value));
        }
        static ulong ClearRandomBit(ulong value)
        {
            // Algorithm from http://graphics.stanford.edu/~seander/bithacks.html
            //
            //   "Select the bit position (from the most-significant bit) with the 
            //   given count (rank)."
            //   
            //   The following 64-bit code selects the position of the rth 1 bit when
            //   counting from the left. In other words if we start at the most 
            //   significant bit and proceed to the right, counting the number of bits
            //   set to 1 until we reach the desired rank, r, then the position where 
            //   we stop will be the final value given to s.

            // Do a normal parallel bit count for a 64-bit integer,                     
            // but store all intermediate steps.
            ulong v = value;
            ulong a = v - ((v >> 1) & ~0UL / 3);
            ulong b = (a & ~0UL / 5) + ((a >> 2) & ~0UL / 5);
            ulong c = (b + (b >> 4)) & ~0UL / 0x11;
            ulong d = (c + (c >> 8)) & ~0UL / 0x101;
            ulong t = (uint)((d >> 32) + (d >> 48));

            // Choose a random r in the range [1-bitCount]
            int bitCount = (int)((d * (~0UL / 255)) >> 56);
            int randomRank = 1 + random.Next(bitCount);
            ulong r = (ulong)randomRank;

            // Compute s                                       
            ulong s = 64;
            s -= ((t - r) & 256UL) >> 3;
            r -= (t & ((t - r) >> 8));
            t = (d >> (int)(s - 16)) & 0xff;
            s -= ((t - r) & 256UL) >> 4;
            r -= (t & ((t - r) >> 8));
            t = (c >> (int)(s - 8)) & 0xf;
            s -= ((t - r) & 256UL) >> 5;
            r -= (t & ((t - r) >> 8));
            t = (b >> (int)(s - 4)) & 0xf;
            s -= ((t - r) & 256UL) >> 6;
            r -= (t & ((t - r) >> 8));
            t = (a >> (int)(s - 2)) & 0x3;
            s -= ((t - r) & 256UL) >> 7;
            r -= (t & ((t - r) >> 8));
            t = (v >> (int)(s - 1)) & 0x1;
            s -= ((t - r) & 256UL) >> 8;
            s = 65 - s;

            // Clear the selected bit
            return value & ~(1UL << (int)(64 - s));
        }
    }
}
```

result;

> Perturb 0.1704681 seconds for 382
>   Perturb 0.9307034 seconds for 256
>   Perturb 0.932266 seconds for 1
>   Perturb 0.4896138 seconds for 257
>   Perturb 0.1541828 seconds for 999
>   Perturb 0.2222421 seconds for 555
>   Perturb 0.2370868 seconds for 412
>   Perturb 0.2229154 seconds for 341
>   Perturb 0.2233445 seconds for 682
>   Perturb 0.1554396 seconds for 951
>   FastPerturb 0.2988974 seconds for 382
>   FastPerturb 1.8008209 seconds for 256
>   FastPerturb 1.7966043 seconds for 1
>   FastPerturb 0.9255025 seconds for 257
>   FastPerturb 0.2708695 seconds for 999
>   FastPerturb 0.4036553 seconds for 555
>   FastPerturb 0.401872 seconds for 412
>   FastPerturb 0.4042984 seconds for 341
>   FastPerturb 0.4028209 seconds for 682
>   FastPerturb 0.2688467 seconds for 951
>   SetRandomTrueBitToFalse 0.6127648 seconds for 382
>   SetRandomTrueBitToFalse 0.4432519 seconds for 256
>   SetRandomTrueBitToFalse 0.4193295 seconds for 1
>   SetRandomTrueBitToFalse 0.4543657 seconds for 257
>   SetRandomTrueBitToFalse 0.6270696 seconds for 999
>   SetRandomTrueBitToFalse 0.5891294 seconds for 555
>   SetRandomTrueBitToFalse 0.5910375 seconds for 412
>   SetRandomTrueBitToFalse 0.6104247 seconds for 341
>   SetRandomTrueBitToFalse 0.6249519 seconds for 682
>   SetRandomTrueBitToFalse 0.6142904 seconds for 951
>   flipRandomBit 0.1624584 seconds for 382
>   flipRandomBit 0.1284565 seconds for 256
>   flipRandomBit 0.13208 seconds for 1
>   flipRandomBit 0.1383649 seconds for 257
>   flipRandomBit 0.1658636 seconds for 999
>   flipRandomBit 0.1563506 seconds for 555
>   flipRandomBit 0.1588513 seconds for 412
>   flipRandomBit 0.1561841 seconds for 341
>   flipRandomBit 0.1562256 seconds for 682
>   flipRandomBit 0.167605 seconds for 951
>   oneBitsIndexes 2.1871352 seconds for 382
>   oneBitsIndexes 1.8677352 seconds for 256
>   oneBitsIndexes 1.8389871 seconds for 1
>   oneBitsIndexes 1.8729746 seconds for 257
>   oneBitsIndexes 2.1821771 seconds for 999
>   oneBitsIndexes 2.1300304 seconds for 555
>   oneBitsIndexes 2.1098191 seconds for 412
>   oneBitsIndexes 2.0836421 seconds for 341
>   oneBitsIndexes 2.0803612 seconds for 682
>   oneBitsIndexes 2.1684378 seconds for 951
>   ClearOneBit 0.3005068 seconds for 382
>   ClearOneBit 1.7872318 seconds for 256
>   ClearOneBit 1.7902597 seconds for 1
>   ClearOneBit 0.9243212 seconds for 257
>   ClearOneBit 0.2666008 seconds for 999
>   ClearOneBit 0.3929297 seconds for 555
>   ClearOneBit 0.3964557 seconds for 412
>   ClearOneBit 0.3945432 seconds for 341
>   ClearOneBit 0.3936286 seconds for 682
>   ClearOneBit 0.2686803 seconds for 951
>   FlipRandomTrueBit 1.5828644 seconds for 382
>   FlipRandomTrueBit 1.3162437 seconds for 256
>   FlipRandomTrueBit 1.2944724 seconds for 1
>   FlipRandomTrueBit 1.3305612 seconds for 257
>   FlipRandomTrueBit 1.5845461 seconds for 999
>   FlipRandomTrueBit 1.5252726 seconds for 555
>   FlipRandomTrueBit 1.5786568 seconds for 412
>   FlipRandomTrueBit 1.5314749 seconds for 341
>   FlipRandomTrueBit 1.5311035 seconds for 682
>   FlipRandomTrueBit 1.6164142 seconds for 951
>   ClearRandomBit 0.2681578 seconds for 382
>   ClearRandomBit 0.2728117 seconds for 256
>   ClearRandomBit 0.2685423 seconds for 1
>   ClearRandomBit 0.2626029 seconds for 257
>   ClearRandomBit 0.2623253 seconds for 999
>   ClearRandomBit 0.274382 seconds for 555
>   ClearRandomBit 0.2644288 seconds for 412
>   ClearRandomBit 0.2667171 seconds for 341
>   ClearRandomBit 0.264912 seconds for 682
>   ClearRandomBit 0.2666491 seconds for 951

so in the end, Kyteland is now the winner.

Comment: Seems that this question is provoking a lot of wrong answers!

Comment: it seem yes... (15chars)

Comment: Unusual request. Are you testing an error-detection process?

Comment: what's the why of the why "I simply need to do this, removing a bit from an integer"? I'm awful curious what the use-case is.

Comment: Needs to determine firing order of employees with equivalent (or lack of) talent...

Comment: Perhaps a game with a "Dispel Magic" spell which randomly turns off one spell effect.

Comment: If I had to guess, it would be "I'm using the integer as a bitfield because I'm prematurely optimizing memory usage."

Comment: You should be passing random data into the method you are profiling, not the same value each time. Ideally you would profile from the expected distribution of your inputs but at least profile uniformly from all possible inputs.

Comment: +1, for taking the time to aggregate the answers and benchmark them.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Here's a slightly more efficient version using bit twiddling.

```
    public static int getBitCount(int bits)
    {
        bits = bits - ((bits >> 1) & 0x55555555);
        bits = (bits & 0x33333333) + ((bits >> 2) & 0x33333333);
        return ((bits + (bits >> 4) & 0xF0F0F0F) * 0x1010101) >> 24;
    }

    public static int flipRandomBit(int data)
    {
        int index = random.Next(getBitCount(data));
        int mask = data;

        for (int i = 0; i < index; i++)
            mask &= mask - 1;
        mask ^= mask & (mask - 1);

        return data ^ mask;
    }
```

Comment: wow, this is faster yes, I will update my post tomorrow so I can test on the same computer I used for my other test. You might get the green check :-)

Comment: It's about 20% faster on a random number and 35% faster on the specific number you used.  I'm sure it could be optimized more but I'm not terribly familiar with c#.

Comment: About 25% faster on my computer, and passes all my tests.  Impressive!

Comment: You may be able to improve the performance of this by using a faster bit counting method.  Check out this site for some benches. http://gurmeetsingh.wordpress.com/2008/08/05/fast-bit-counting-routines/

Comment: I did a breakdown of flipRandomBit.  getBitCount accounts for 10% of the processing time and random.Next takes 40% which leaves 50% for the for loop and xor'ing.  I made the classic mistake of optimizing before profiling the code.  I didn't notice any difference in performance using Precompute_16bit.

Comment: In case anyone is puzzled by how the last part of this algorithm works, `x &= x - 1` is a neat trick for clearing the least significant set bit. See http://www-graphics.stanford.edu/~seander/bithacks.html#CountBitsSetKernighan

Answer (score 15):

```
static Random random = new Random();

public static int Perturb(int data)
{
    if (data == 0) return 0;

    // attempt to pick a more narrow search space
    int minBits = (data & 0xFFFF0000) == 0 ? 16 : 32;

    // int used = 0; // Uncomment for more-bounded performance
    int newData = data;
    do
    {
        // Unbounded performance guarantees
        newData &= ~(1 << random.Next(minBits));

        // // More-bounded performance:
        // int bit = 1 << random.Next(minBits);
        // if ((used & bit) == bit) continue;
        // used |= bit;
        // newData &= ~bit;
    } while (newData == data); // XXX: we know we've inverted at least one 1
                               // when the new value differs

    return newData;
}
```

**Update**: added code above which can be used for more-bounded performance guarantees (or less unbounded if you want to think of it that way). Interestingly enough this performs better than the original uncommented version.

Below is an alternate approach that is fast but without bounded performance guarantees:

```
public static int FastPerturb(int data)
{
    if (data == 0) return 0;

    int bit = 0;
    while (0 == (data & (bit = 1 << random.Next(32))));

    return data & ~bit;
}
```

Comment: Added code to potentially narrow the search space, which improves performance in many cases.

Comment: that FastPerturb should be called slowerPerturb, at least under my test(see my question)

Comment: The timing I received was that there wasn't much of an appreciable difference, but after 100M iterations FastPerturb took 598ms and Perturb took 627ms on average. YMMV :)

Answer (score 4):

*EDIT : fixed to take into account the constraint "a bit which is not 0"*

Pick a random number N between 0 and 31 (for a 32 bit integer), and use it to generate a bitmask by shifting 1 N times to the left. Repeat until bit N is not 0 in the original number. Negate the bitmask to have only 1 bit set to 0 and combine it with your original number with the & operator :

```
private int ClearOneBit(int originalValue)
{
    if (originalValue == 0)
        return 0; // All bits are already set to 0, nothing to do

    Random rnd = new Random();
    int mask = 0;
    do
    {
        int n = rnd.Next(32);
        mask = 1 << n;
    } while ((mask & originalValue) == 0); // check that this bit is not 0

    int newValue = originalValue & ~mask; // clear this bit
    return newValue;
}
```

Comment: This might change a 0 to a 0, which isn't what is required.

Comment: OP only wants 0's changed to 1.

Comment: Could while() around oldPopCnt == newPopCnt.

Comment: I missed the "which is not 0" part... it's fixed now

Comment: Just to double check, do you really want to instantiate a new Random() every time this is called?

Comment: Not if the method is going to be called in a loop, of course... this is not supposed to be production code, just a sample to illustrate the idea

Answer (score 4):

OK:

```
    private static Random rnd = new Random((int)DateTime.Now.Ticks);

    private static Int32 SetRandomTrueBitToFalse(Int32 p)
    {
        List<int> trueBits = new List<int>();
        for (int i = 0; i < 31; i++)
        {
            if ((p>>i&1) == 1){
                trueBits.Add(i);
            }
        }
        if (trueBits.Count>0){
            int index = rnd.Next(0, trueBits.Count);
            return p & ~(1 << trueBits[index]);
        }
        return p;
    }
```

But I would love to know: Why do you need/want this?

Comment: now it's working, I will wait about 1 hours before I give a green check :-)

Comment: Note this is about 5x slower than the other answers due to the memory allocation of the `List<T>`.

Comment: About why:
A & 11101111 will have as result A, with its 4th bit set to 0.
And 11101111 = ~00010000 = ~(1 << 4)

Comment: @sixlettervariables: it may be five times slower, but it has a guaranteed running time. Your answer will be faster in almost all practical cases, but there is a small chance that it loops several 100 times before returning a result. Don't get me wrong, I like your answer!

Comment: Hmm, yay, a compleet list for bitshifting. Awesome difference in size between the target and the utils.

Comment: @Doc Brown: I added some "more-bounded" performance to my original answer. I've also found that if @feihtthief switches to an array of short's hard set to a max of 32, the memory usage is smaller and the runtime is twice as fast (still 2.5x slower, but bounded as you point out).

Comment: I agree with sixletter.  There is no reason to use a List instead a far more efficient array.  That's not premature optimization, that's common sense

Answer (score 3):

You can turn on any bit by OR'ing it with 1 and turn it off by AND'ing with the bitwise complement.

Here's an example that selects a random 1-bit and turns it off.

```
var rand = new Random();
int myValue = 0x017E; // 101111110b
// identify which indexes are one-bits (if any, thanks Doc)
if( myValue > 0 )
{
    var oneBitsIndexes = Enumerable.Range( 0, 31 )
                                   .Where(i => ((myValue >> i) & 0x1) !=0).ToList();
    // pick a random index and update the source value bit there from 1 to 0
    myValue &= ~(1 << oneBitsIndexes[rand.Next(oneBitsIndexes.Count)]);
}
// otherwise, there are no bits to turn off...
```

Comment: I know that, I want it to be random and not touching the 0

Comment: This one might be my favorite, but there is one bug to fix: myValue may be 0!

Comment: @Doc Brown: You are correct, that's an edge case that would crash with an IndexOutOfRangeException. I've fixed the code.

Comment: @LBushkin - I am tryiing to give you +1, but SO says "Vote too old to be changed". Perhaps you can make a minor change to it, so I can upvote your answer?

Comment: @Doc: Brown: I made a minor change indeed. I fixed it because I carelessly copied the binary value for the example; forgetting for a moment that C# has no way to express values in binary. Changed that to hex.

Comment: copying this code in a fresh new console app (c#) under vs2008 doesn't run, a few errors.

Comment: @LBushkin: I will give you +1 when you write .Where(i => ((myValue >> i) & 0x1) !=0).ToList() and rand.Next instead of rand.NextValue

Comment: @Fredou: apply my suggested changes and try again.

Comment: with doc brown suggestion, it's working, 3th for now. I need to leave for a meeting now, back in about 1 hour with a green check for someone.

Answer (score 1):

You can generalize this by using BitArray.

```
public static BitArray FlipRandomTrueBit(BitArray bits)
{
    List<int> trueBits = new List<int>();

    for (int i = 0; i < bits.Count; i++)
        if (bits[i])
            trueBits.Add(i);

    if (trueBits.Count > 0)
    {
        int index = rnd.Next(0, trueBits.Count);
        bits[trueBits[index]] = false;
    }

    return bits;
}
```

However then you will have to write helper functions for simple data types.

```
public static int FlipRandomTrueBit(int input)
{
    BitArray bits = new BitArray(new int[] { input });
    BitArray flipedBits = FlipRandomTrueBit(bits);

    byte[] bytes = new byte[4];
    flipedBits.CopyTo(bytes, 0);

    int result = BitConverter.ToInt32(bytes, 0);
    return result;
}
```

If your using a large bit array you could save memory by iterating twice.

```
public static void FlipRandomTrueBitLowMem(ref BitArray bits)
{
    int trueBits = 0;

    for (int i = 0; i < bits.Count; i++)
        if (bits[i])
            trueBits++;

    if (trueBits > 0)
    {
        int flip = rnd.Next(0, trueBits);

        for (int i = 0; i < bits.Count; i++)
        {
            if (bits[i])
            {
                if (flip == 0)
                {
                    bits[i] = false;
                    break;
                }

                flip--;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Test Program.

```
using System;
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;

namespace bitarray
{
    class Program
    {
        private static Random rnd = new Random((int)DateTime.Now.Ticks);

        public static BitArray FlipRandomTrueBit(BitArray bits)
        {
            List<int> trueBits = new List<int>();

            for (int i = 0; i < bits.Count; i++)
                if (bits[i])
                    trueBits.Add(i);

            if (trueBits.Count > 0)
            {
                int index = rnd.Next(0, trueBits.Count);
                bits[trueBits[index]] = false;
            }

            return bits;
        }

        public static int FlipRandomTrueBit(int input)
        {
            BitArray bits = new BitArray(new int[] { input });
            BitArray flipedBits = FlipRandomTrueBit(bits);

            byte[] bytes = new byte[4];
            flipedBits.CopyTo(bytes, 0);

            int result = BitConverter.ToInt32(bytes, 0);
            return result;
        }

        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            int test = 382;
            for (int n = 0; n < 200; n++)
            {
                int result = FlipRandomTrueBit(test);
                Console.WriteLine(result);
            }

            Console.ReadLine();
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try the following code

```
public static int ChangeOneBit(int data)
{
    if (data == 0)
    {
        return data;
    }

    var random = new Random();
    int bit = 0;
    do
    {
        var shift = random.Next(31);
        bit = data >> shift;
        bit = bit & 0x00000001;
    } while (bit == 0);
    var ret = data & (~(1 << bit));
    return ret;
}
```

Comment: This answer is almost correct, you just switched a bit that is 1 to 0, the OP wants it vice versa. I remove the downvoting if you fix the answer.

Comment: The OP wants a bit to be 0 that was once 1.

Comment: This is simpler if done with LINQ, IMO. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2001597/how-to-randomly-remove-a-bit-from-an-integer/2001634#2001634

Comment: The problem i see with this is that the randomly generated shift could keep on missing the 1 in the data for an indeterminate period.

Comment: this seem to always remove the first bit, always return 380

Comment: @JaredPar: this always produces the same values.

Answer (score 0):

EDIT: Fixed some logic.

```
BitArray bits = new BitArray(new int[] { number } );

randomIndex = new Random().Next(32);

// check if bit is true, if not, goes to next bit and wraps around as well.
for(int i = 0; i < 32; i++)
{
    if(bits[randomIndex] == false)
    {
    randomIndex = (randomIndex + 1) % 32;
    }
    else
    {
        break;
    }
}

bits[randomIndex] = false;
```

Comment: How? It's in a for loop that stops after 32 iterations.

Comment: Sorry, wrong comment of mine. The solution is correct, but it does not switch all 1 bits with an equal chance (the OP did not say if he wants that, but I suspect he does).

Comment: I believe JP772's solution to be the most straightforward and correct one.

Comment: @CookieOfFortune: except that he switches 0 to 1, and not 1 to 0, as the OP asked for.

Answer (score 0):

Count all the 1's in your integer.
Choose a random number using your favorite random number generator between 1 and the first count.
Create a mask for Random-th 1 in your integer.
OR your integer with the mask.

Comment: Do you mean AND? I fail to see how an OR could possibly turn a 1 into a 0.

Comment: You want to XOR your integer with the mask, not OR it. Otherwise, you are correct.

Comment: Sorry, should've reread that before posting. AND or XOR, depending on the "polarity" of the mask.

Answer (score 0):

```
int changeBit(int a)
{
    a = ~a;
    int temp = a;
    while(temp == a)
    {
        r = Math.pow(2,(int)(32*random.next()));
        a = a || r;    
    }

    return ~a;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Ok, a lot of wrong answers. Here's one that works:

1. determine which bit to flip. Do this randomly. I won't supply the code, it's pretty straightforward.
2. setup a bitmask with all zeros, with a 1 for the bit in question. So for example, if it's the 3rd bit, your bitmask might be 00000100. Again, this doesn't require code.
3. bitwise [**XOR**](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Exclusive_or) your number with the bit mask. If you're unfamiliar with the operator it's the hat operator: `^`

Here's some sample code:

```
int myInt; // set this up with your original value
int myBitmask; // set this up with the bit mask via steps 1 and 2.
int randomlyZeroedBitInt = myInt ^ myBitmask;
```

**Edit:** On a fifth read of the question, I have a question in return: you are wanting to do which of the following:

1. Randomly zero a bit, but only if that bit is already 1. In other words, if the bit in question isn't already 1, the operation is a no-op.
2. Randomly choose a bit that is 1 and zero it. This operation always chooses a bit that is already 1 and always zeros it. The operation is only a no-op if the original value is 0.

**Edit 2:**

> 2 is correct,(15chars) – Fredou

In that case, my general algorithm stands; merely choose the bit in step 1 with internal logic. Alternatively, choose a fully random bit in step 1 and repeat until the value of myInt and randomlyZeroedBitInt are not equal.

Unfortunately either case means a more complex algorithm, as you'll either need to iterate over every bit in your value to determine which to flip, or you'll need to loop the algorithm until a bit is flipped.

Answer (score 0):

Here is a version based on an [algorithm](http://graphics.stanford.edu/~seander/bithacks.html##SelectPosFromMSBRank) from [Bit Twiddling Hacks](http://graphics.stanford.edu/~seander/bithacks.html) to select the nth set bit of an integer. For this case, we simply select n at random.

The code has been ported to C#, made to work directly on 32-bit signed integers, and count from the right instead of the left. Furthermore, the optimization to remove all branches has not been preserved here as it yielded slower code on my machine (Intel Core 2 Quad Q9450).

The description on the Bit Twiddling Hacks page does not give much insight into how the algorithm works. I have taken the time to step through and reverse engineer it and what I found is described in detail in the comments below.

In my tests, this algorithm performs very similarly to Kyteland's excellent flipRandomBit over input that is distributed randomly across the full range of 32-bit integers. However, flipRandomBit is slightly faster for numbers with significantly fewer set bits than cleared bits. Conversely, this algorithm is slightly faster for numbers with significantly more set bits than cleared bits.

The OP's benchmark consists entirely of small positive integers, which do not stress flipRandomBit's worst case. If this is an indication of the expected input, then all the more reason to prefer flipRandomBit.

```
static int ClearRandomSetBit(int input) {
    ///////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
    // ** Step 1 **
    // Count the set bits
    ////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////

    // magic numbers
    const int m2 = 0x55555555; // 1 zero,  1 one,  ...
    const int m4 = 0x33333333; // 2 zeros, 2 ones, ...
    const int m8 = 0x0f0f0f0f; // 4 zeros, 4 ones, ...

    // sequence of 2-bit values representing the counts of each 2 bits.
    int c2 = input - ((input >> 1) & m2);

    // sequence of 4-bit values representing the counts of each 4 bits.
    int c4 = (c2 & m4) + ((c2 >> 2) & m4);

    // sequence of 8-bit values representing the counts of each 8 bits.
    int c8 = (c4 + (c4 >> 4)) & m8;

    // count set bits in input.
    int bitCount = (c8 * 0x1010101) >> 24;

    ///////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
    // ** Step 2 ** 
    // Select a random set bit to clear and find it using binary search with our 
    // knowledge of the bit counts in the various regions.
    ///////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////

    // count 16 right-most bits where we'll begin our search
    int count = (c8 + (c8 >> 8)) & 0xff;

    // position of target bit among the set bits
    int target = random.Next(bitCount);

    // distance in set bits from the current position to the target
    int distance = target + 1;

    // current bit position 
    int pos = 0;

    // if the target is not in the right-most 16 bits, move past them
    if (distance > count) { pos += 16; distance -= count; }

    // if the target is not in the next 8 bits, move past them
    count = (c8 >> pos) & 0xff;
    if (distance > count) { pos += 8; distance -= count; }

    // if the target is not in the next 4 bits, move past them
    count = (c4 >> pos) & 0xf;
    if (distance > count) { pos += 4; distance -= count; }

    // if the target is not in the next 2 bits, move past them
    count = (c2 >> pos) & 0x3;
    if (distance > count) { pos += 2; distance -= count; }

    // if the bit is not the next bit, move past it.
    //
    // Note that distance and count must be single bits by now.
    // As such, distance is greater than count if and only if 
    // distance equals 1 and count equals 0. This obversation
    // allows us to optimize away the final branch.
    Debug.Assert((distance & 0x1) == distance);
    Debug.Assert((count & 0x1) == count);
    count = (input >> pos) & 0x1;
    pos += (distance & (count ^ 1));

    Debug.Assert((input & (1 << pos)) != 0);
    return input ^ (1 << pos);
}
```

Answer (score -1):

```
 int val=382

 int mask = ~(1 << N)   

 // this would turn-off nth bit (0 to 31)
 NewVal = (int) ((uint)val & (uint)mask}
```