# C# How to remove the n-th bit in integer?

Tags: c#, bit-manipulation

I am trying to find a way to remove a bit from an integer. The solution must not use string operations.
For example, I have the number 27, which is 1**1**011 in binary.
I want to remove the third bit so it leaves me with 1011.
Or we have 182 (10110110), remove the 6th bit so the result is 1110110 (which is 118). I am trying to think of the algorithm how to do that, but so far no luck, and I can't find useful information on the internet.

I know how to use bitwise operators and how to extract or manipulate bits in integers (change values, exchange values etc), but I don't know how to 'remove' a certain bit.

I am not looking for code, just the logic of the operation. If anyone could help me, that would be awesome!

Regards,
Toni

Comment: possible duplicate of [How do you randomly zero a bit in an integer?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2001597/how-do-you-randomly-zero-a-bit-in-an-integer)

Comment: You can't really remove a bit, all you can do it make it a 0.  So using bitwise operation 01011 & 11011 = 01011 = 1011 = 00000000000000000000000000001011 (int32).  Only way to remove it is to actually represent it as a string and then any conversion back to int will just make it have the 0 again.

Comment: @Mgetz The task is not to set a bit to zero, but to completely remove it.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

No problem, just decompose the number into the "upper part" and the "lower part", and put them together without the middle bit that now disappeared.

Not tested:

```
uint upper = x & 0xFFFFFFF0;
uint lower = x & 7;
return (upper >> 1) | lower;
```

More generally: (also not tested)

```
uint upper = x & (0xFFFFFFFE << n);
uint lower = x & ((1u << n) - 1);
return (upper >> 1) | lower;
```

Comment: Be warned that bit-shift operators "copy" the highest bit, so might be a bit strange if your highest bit is `1`

Comment: @Aravol that's why I used `uint`

Comment: Thanks @harold after I gave it a good thinking I thought of something similar. I am glad to see now that my idea wasn't stupid :)

Answer (score 1):

In order to do this you need two bit masks and a shift.

The first bit mask gives you the portion of the number above bit `n`, exclusive of the `n`-th bit. The mask is constructed as follows:

```
var top = ~((1U<<(n+1))-1); // 1111 1111 1000 000, 0xFF80
```

The second bit mask gives you the portion of the number below bit `n`, exclusive of the `n`-th bit:

```
var bottom = (1U<<n)-1;     // 0000 0000 0011 1111, 0x003F
```

Comments above show the values for your second example (i.e. `n == 6`)

With the two masks in hand, you can construct the result as follows:

```
var res = ((original & top)>>1) | (original & bottom);
```

[Demo.](http://ideone.com/gy9ZfM)

Comment: Thanks! I think of something similar.

Comment: `int input = int.Parse(Console.ReadLine());

int left = (input >> (n+1))<<(n+1);

int right = (input << (31-n))>>(31-n);

int result = left | right;`

Comment: This will fail for n=31, since shift counts are modulo 32 in C# (and most CPUs).

Answer (score 0):

You could use the following approach:

```
int value = 27;
string binary = Convert.ToString(value, 2);
binary = binary.Remove(binary.Length-3-1,1);  //Remove the exact bit, 3rd in this case
int newValue = Convert.ToInt32(binary, 2);
Console.WriteLine(newValue);
```

Hope it helps!

Comment: This is a cool, but the idea is to solve it with bitwise operators, not string. Thanks for the hint though!

Answer (score 0):

```
  int Place = 7;
  int TheInt = 182;

  string binary = Convert.ToString(TheInt, 2);
  MessageBox.Show(binary.Remove(binary.Length - Place, 1));
```

Comment: Don't post code-only answers.  Please provide an explanation

Comment: The task is to do it without using strings. Only bitwise operators.

Comment: @tony Neither of those things were mentioned in your question. If so, it would have saved me some time.

Answer (score 0):

Here is a version that needs slightly fewer operations than the solution by harold:

```
x ^ (((x >> 1) ^ x) & (0xffffffff << n));
```

The idea is that below `n`, bits are xored with zero, leaving them unchanged, while from n and above the two `x` xored cancel each other out, leaving `x >> 1`.

Answer (score 0):

```
        int a = 27;//int= 4byte equal to 32 bit
        string binary = "";
        for (int i = 0; i < 32; i++)
        {             
            if ((a&1)==0)//if a's least significant bit is 0 ,add 0 to str
            {
                binary = "0" + binary;
            }
            else//if a's least significant bit is 1 ,add 1 to str
            {
                binary = "1" + binary;
            }
            a = a >> 1;//shift the bits left to right and delete lsb
            //we are doing it for 32 times because integer have 32 bit.
        }
        Console.WriteLine("Integer to Binary= "+binary);

     //Now you can operate the string(binary) however you want.

      binary = binary.Remove(binary.Length-4,1);//remove 4st bit from str
```

Comment: i edited the code, "int value = 27;string binary = Convert.ToString(value, 2);" is also do the same thing.the code is different way for convert integer to binary.